# Cloudera Docker keeps retrying to connect to 8032

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I use the docker image from [cloudera](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/quickstart_docker_container.html), but it seems the configuration not quite right. Because I do this:

```sh
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop*/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming*cdh*.jar \
  -mapper mapper -reducer reducer \
  -file mapper -file reducer \
  -input input -output output
```

I got this all the time:

```
18/03/14 02:34:33 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

This is how I did prior to running the process above.

1. Increase Docker memory into 8GB
2. Start the container, by running this in the host

```sh
docker run -p 7180:7180 \
  --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true \
  -t -i cloudera/quickstart:latest \
  /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

3. Start the manager
   /home/cloudera/cloudera-manager --express
4. Open cloudera manager to start HDFS
5. Upload sample input into HDFS

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the manager to start not just HDFS, but also YARN